# Live motion information of the Apple Watch in an iPhone app

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, core-motion, watchos

Inside the iPhone app, I would need live motion information from the sensors in the Apple Watch.
I know it's possible to send live messages from the watch to the iPhone, but I would like to know if it's possible to do so constantly (around 10 updates/second) and for an extended period (several minutes)? 
That's is to say, I'd like the watch to keep sending live motion updates to the iPhone app even when both the watch and the iPhone are in background.
Is that possible?